# how to split array into given number in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-splice

I have an array and i have to split it into given number and last splited array should accommodate remaining elements if (remaining array size < given_no/2)

for example

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

if given_no 2 = Math.round(arr.length/2)= chunk_size 6 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[6,7,8,9,10]] 
if given_no 3 = Math.round(arr.length/3)= chunk_size 4 = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11]]
if given_no 4 = Math.round(arr.length/4)= chunk_size 3 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11]]
```

Comment: give_number is only till 4 or is it dynamic ?

Comment: `Math.round(11/2) == 6`, not `5`.  Did you mean `Math.floor(11/2)`? - If so, `Math.floor(11/3) == 3` and `Math.floor(11/4) == 2`...
Also, I'm unclear about "if (remaining array size < given_no/2)".

Comment: @SijuSamson..its dynamic (given_no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Math.round(arr.length/2) will return 6 not 5.
Please see below code. I have created splitArr function which will return split array based on given number.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
console.log('Given 2: ' + JSON.stringify(splitArr(arr, 2))); // given 2
console.log('Given 3: ' + JSON.stringify(splitArr(arr, 3))); // given 3
console.log('Given 4: ' + JSON.stringify(splitArr(arr, 4))); // given 4
console.log('Given 5: ' + JSON.stringify(splitArr(arr, 5))); // given 5
console.log('Given 6: ' + JSON.stringify(splitArr(arr, 6))); // given 6

    function splitArr(arr, given) {
      var arrSize = arr.length
      var split = Math.round(arrSize/given);
      var returnArr = [];
      var loopCount;
      for(i = 0; i < given; i++){
        loopCount = (i*split)+split;
        loopCount = loopCount > arrSize ? arrSize : loopCount;
        
        var innerArr = arr.slice((i*split), loopCount)

        returnArr.push(innerArr);
      }

      if(loopCount < arr.length){
         innerArr.push(...arr.slice(loopCount, arrSize));
      }
      
      return returnArr;
    }
```

Comment: It fails for => splitArr(5); // given 5 => Given 5: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]...where is element '11'

Comment: @NRaj please verify edited answer and upvote if it works.

Comment: How about performance , If array size in beween 100k to 500k?

Comment: Improved my answer please verify that. Removed 2 inner for loops this will improve performance.

Comment: For give = 5, you seem to have the further nesting:
`Given 5: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10,[11]]]`. You have `[9, 10, [11]]`

Comment: check now it fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.round()` and `array.slice()`.

```js
var splitArray = (arr, num) => {
    let result = [];
    let size   = Math.round(arr.length/num); 
    for (let i=0; i<num; i++) {
        let end = i === num-1 ? arr.length : (i+1) * size;
        result.push(arr.slice(i*size, end));
    }
    return result;  
} 

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitArray(arr, 2)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitArray(arr, 3)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitArray(arr, 4)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(splitArray(arr, 5)));
```

Comment: this is not working with console.log(JSON.stringify(splitArray(arr, 5)));

Comment: Yes, this also fails for console.log(JSON.stringify(splitArray(arr, 5)));

Comment: OK `Math.round()` it is. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function splitintochunks(arr,l){
    let result=[];
    while(arr.length>0){
    result.push(arr.splice(0,l));
    }
    return result;
}
//EXAMPLE: call in the below way spltIntoChunks([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],5);
```

Comment: This will not work, please test it once, and then give appropriate result.

Comment: @SijuSamson, got my mistake , thanks :) for adding the comment